# Given string is not converting into camelCase in python?

Tags: python, string, function, python-module, camelcasing

Recently I have a made a `function` in python which converts any string in `camelCase` format, but while passing different types of string in this function I got into a problem when I tried to pass `"BirdFlight"` it did not convert it into `camelCase`.

**NOTE** - I used python built-in `re` module.

```py
import re

def camelCase(string):
    string = re.sub(r'(_|-)+', ' ', string).title().replace(' ', '')
    
    return ''.join([string[0].lower() + string[1:]])
```

After that I created a `list` of 3 different types of string to pass in the function.

```py
differentTypeOfString = ['bird flight', 'BirdFlight', '-BIRD-FLIGHT-']

for i in differentTypeOfString:
    print(camelCase(i))
```

*ignore the varialbe name I will change it after.*

**OUTPUT**

```
#1 birdFlight
#2 birdflight
#3 birdFlight
```

Well there are more problems I encountered just now . I increased the string types inside my list:

```py
differentTypeOfString = ['bird flight', 'BirdFlight', '-BIRD-FLIGHT-', 'Bird-Flight', 'bird_flight', '--bird.flight', 'Bird-FLIGHT', 'birdFLIGHT']
```

Now I am getting this Output

```
#1 birdFlight
#2 birdflight
#3 birdFlight
#4 birdFlight
#5 birdFlight
#6 bird.Flight
#7 birdFlight
#8 birdflight
```

Same problem with `"birdFLIGHT"`and in `"--bird.flight"` the "." (dot) is not removing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your current examples.  The `re.sub` adds a space between any existing <lower><upper> sequence.

```py
import re

def camelCase(string):
    string = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]))|[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', string).title().replace(' ', '')
    return ''.join([string[0].lower() + string[1:]])

differentTypeOfString = ['bird flight', 'BirdFlight', '-BIRD-FLIGHT-', 'Bird-Flight', 'bird_flight', '--bird.flight', 'Bird-FLIGHT', 'birdFLIGHT']

for i in differentTypeOfString:
    print(camelCase(i))
```

Output:

```
birdFlight
birdFlight
birdFlight
birdFlight
birdFlight
birdFlight
birdFlight
birdFlight
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest `re.findall` (or even `re.finditer`), and make the regex such that a word break is guaranteed between a lowercase and uppercase letter:

```
def camelCase(string):
    return "".join(word.title() if i else word.lower()
        for i, word in enumerate(re.finditer(r"[A-Z]*[a-z]+|[A-Z]+", string))
    )
```

For the following testcases the output is `birdFlight`:

```
['bird flight', 'BirdFlight', '-BIRD-FLIGHT-', 'Bird-Flight', 
 'bird_flight', '--bird.flight', 'Bird-FLIGHT', 'birdFLIGHT']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `findall` with just looking for `'\w+'`, then `.title` every word. Then just lowercase the first character

```
def camelCase(s):
    titled = ''.join(i.title() for i in re.findall('\w+', i))
    return titled[0].lower() + titled[1:]
```

Then your example

```
differentTypeOfString = ['bird flight', 'BirdFlight', '-BIRD-FLIGHT-']
for i in differentTypeOfString:
    print(camelCase(i))
```

output

```
birdFlight
birdflight
birdFlight
```

Comment: Now I increased my ```list``` and it is not working with the recently added elements or string types.

Comment: @KunalTanwar For `'birdFLIGHT'` how are you supposed to know it should be `'birdFlight'` and not `'birdflight'`? Is it because there is a lowercase to uppercase change between `d` and `F`?

Comment: That is all the game about!!  I know that but I want python to this about itself.